# How do I properly render OpenGL inside of a Win32(C++) static control?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am trying to get OpenGL to render inside of a Win32 api static control. I've gone through Nehe's tutorial (http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/) on how to force openGl to render to an entire window. I understand how to do that but I'm not totally sure how to get it to render inside of a static control(or any control). Currently, I am trying to do this:

```
HDC         hDC = NULL;
HGLRC       hRC = NULL; 
HWND        hWnd = NULL; 
HWND        panel;
HINSTANCE   hInstance;  
void CreatePanelGL(HWND hWnd){
    panel = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    "STATIC",
    "",
    WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | CS_OWNDC | CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW,
    30, 30, 100, 100,
    hWnd,
    (HMENU)BUTTON_ID,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);

    hDC = GetDC(panel);
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { 0 };
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.cStencilBits = 8;

    SetPixelFormat(hDC, 1, &pfd);
    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){
switch(uMsg){
   case WM_CREATE:{
      CreatePanelGL(hWnd);
      break;
   }}
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I have way more code than this but I figured this is the only important bits. If you want me to post more, let me know. The callback function is cut down by a lot, the CreatePanelGL() function is a complete copy and paste. The code is pretty much a heavily modified version of Nehe's code. While this is not throwing any errors, openGl is not rendering the clear color inside of the panel. Can anyone help me out? I'm sure I am doing at least a hundred things wrong.

Comment: Have to tried subclassing the control and overriding its paint messages and doing nothing in them or drawing in them with OpenGL?

Comment: @ Calvin: I will take a look at using a custom control
@Brandon: Right now I just have OpenGL clearing with a color, I haven't done anything with the control paint messages. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Static control` has its own drawing operations that may mess things up. Create a custom child window instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I looked up making custom controls and managed to find some sample code in c. I get how to do that but I am still confused on how I would get OpenGl to draw into it. I'm assuming I would have a new control class with its own register,unregister, and callback functions.In the callback function I assume I would need to take over WM_PAINT in the callback function but I don't understand how I would do that. Could you go more in depth with your answer?

Comment: I'm not going to dig into details here, you should find a tutorial for that. Google it, or visit http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/. And no NeHe, it was good but now it's considered seriously outdated with ancient GL version.

Comment: The reason why I am asking it because I was not able to find a tutorial for what I am trying to do. That site also doesn't have a tutorial on what I am trying to do, and has nothing related to the Win32 api or controls. A few more details would be really nice.